# Firewall to accept only Wikipedia traffic

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables

I have a challenge where I need to accept only traffic from Wikipedia.org
I am familiar with `iptables` and understand network basics.

For Facebook traffic, I could use

```
whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route
```

to get list of Facebook IP addresses.

Is there a similar way for Wikipedia.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ dig +short www.wikipedia.org. a
91.198.174.192
$ whois -h whois.radb.net 91.198.174.192 |grep ^origin
origin:         AS43821
$ whois -h whois.radb.net \!gAS43821
A31
185.15.56.0/22 91.198.174.0/24
C
```

So your answer would be: 185.15.56.0/22 91.198.174.0/24

Some credits go to this question (seems the "!g" query gives an easier result that the "-i origin" one. Beware ! often needs a \ if shell is interactive, quotes won't do it):
https://serverfault.com/questions/802142/dont-work-scipt-with-output-drop-policy-in-iptables

Comment: Good answer. Thanks to both question and answer (both upvoted), I now know that the `whois` command has more useful features than I had previously realised. The man page and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS are well worth reading.

Comment: neat answer. I am getting different set of results dig +short www.wikipedia.org. a
208.80.154.224
 whois -h whois.radb.net 208.80.154.224 |grep ^origin
origin:         AS14907
whois -h whois.radb.net \!gAS14907
208.80.152.0/22 198.35.26.0/23 208.80.152.0/23 208.80.154.0/23

Comment: Perhaps the DNS server uses geolocalisation? Might be hard to know all their networks then, but if it's stable at the place of usage...

Comment: that's it: my net was actually named: route: 91.198.174.0/24 descr:          Wikimedia Europe network (and i'm in Europe)